# How to use and specify Generic Hooks in React with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a generic hooks to handle the button input elements, which return array of input value, bind object and reset handler.

**Component**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useInput } from "../services/FormInputHooks";

export type AddTransactionProps = {};

export const AddTransaction: React.FC<AddTransactionProps> = () => {
    const [text, bindText, resetText] = useInput<string>("");
    const [amount, bindAmount, resetAmount] = useInput<number>(0.0);

    return (
        <>
            <h3>Add new transaction</h3>
            <form>
                <div className="form-control">
                    <label htmlFor="text">Text</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        {...bindText}
                        placeholder="Enter text.."
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-control">
                    <label htmlFor="amount">
                        Amount <br />
                        (negative - expense, positive - income)
                    </label>
                    <input
                        type="number"
                        {...bindAmount}
                        placeholder="Enter amount.."
                    />
                </div>
                <button className="btn"> Add Transaction</button>
            </form>
        </>
    );
};

export default AddTransaction;
```

**Hook**

```js
import { useState } from "react";

export function useInput<T>(
    initialValue: T
): [T, any, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>] {
    const [value, setValue] = useState<T>(initialValue);

    const reset = () => {
        setValue(initialValue);
    };

    const bind = {
        value,
        onChange: e => {
            setValue(e.target.value);
        }
    };

    return [value, bind, reset];
}
```

**Problem I'm Facing**

```
Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type.  TS7006

    12 |     const bind = {
    13 |         value,
  > 14 |         onChange: e => {
       |                   ^
    15 |             setValue(e.target.value);
    16 |         }
    17 |     };
```

Though i've specified the type of any for the bind object, it shows the above error. I've even tried with following code to specify the return type.

```js
[T, {T: onChange: (e: any) => void}, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is not the type you define for the hooks return value, it is that the bind object does not have any type annotation so its `onChange` method's `e` param will be implicitly any.

One possible sulution to fix its type annotation:

```
import { useState, ChangeEventHandler } from "react";

interface ResetFunction {
    (): void
}

interface Bind<T> {
  value: T,
  onChange: ChangeEventHandler<any>
}

export function useInput<T>(
    initialValue: T
): [T, Bind<T>, ResetFunction] {
    const [value, setValue] = useState<T>(initialValue);

    const reset = () => {
        setValue(initialValue);
    };

    const bind: Bind<T> = {
        value,
        onChange: e => {
            setValue(e.target.value);
        }
    };

    return [value, bind, reset];
}
```

[Typescipt playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN0A0cAwgBY4B2A5ugKIBu6FMAEpQCYA26UcAvnABmUCCDgAiKOhwBjGOIDcAKCXBmPQbPRwASugwwAYsgpzgECoiVwbcABQBKAFxx6EYOyV8Va-FE0y2gBCauwAPAAqAHxWNvQ4nMjoLhEE1nAWZJQ0LlnUdIzMbBRcPGGUAJ5RXiroAB6QsEImZhYoGACSFGDIMJFRduk2asAwwAkAaglJKUrOcADaqXAhJf1EegbGpmMWALqxtjIWqPAL8YmEcAZTlwcAvO1YuPj9diNjk9PoDspDcMcKKc4FIDHBHo5wTEEP9bNd0DBbkl3hRRuNOEifso4Xw-nDAcCAEahFyrcLRcGHOFxb5pam2TLkfIubT3aGw%20nwxHfOzoAB0uCgNBgfIuSV%20HJs3hxeNsUhgyCglnOtLgxJKRFBCL2yj4QA)

Comment: I think `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>` would be better for ResetFunction. It's more implicit?? Can you please correct me??

Comment: If you passed the `setValue` from the hook directly, the `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>` would be a correct type, but you don't, you create a new function (reset) which takes no parameter and returns nothing, and it calls your `setValue` function, thus the extra type for `ResetFunction` in my example.

Comment: So `React.Dispatch` specifies the return type to be callable and `React.SetStateAction<T>` for that specific callable to set state. Am i right?? Please share any related docs if you have any. Thanks !!

Comment: I just worked my way through React's type definition. Dispatch type: `type Dispatch<A> = (value: A) => void;`: defines a generic function, which takes a value and returns void. SetStateAction: `type SetStateAction<S> = S | ((prevState: S) => S);`  a generic type, whether the generic value itself or a function which gets a parameter and returns the generic type. So `Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>` will be basically a function which gets a single value or a function (wich gets an `S` and returns an `S`) and returns void.

Answer (score 2):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export function useInput<T>(
    initialValue: T
): [T, any, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>] {
    const [value, setValue] = useState<T>(initialValue);

    const reset = () => {
        setValue(initialValue);
    };

    const bind = {
        value,
        onChange: (e: React.ChangeEvent<any>) => {
            setValue(e.target?.value);
        }
    };

    return [value, bind, reset];
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxJwC+cAZlBCHAERSoYsDcAUD0gA9IsevgB2GYBDEFiASTFh8MADwAVAHwAKHnD1xgY4DGAoANgDVz+JAC44angEp7AbTXYUYgJ7Zk6GAA6ABFgQjAKNAALFX8MQJIkGDIKJABBSWl1DQ0AXVxdfTRpQnhXADdrJGxiGCszG3yAXllSckpsrUNjU0sqp15CvWKxUrh2WrgWrScpjQL9Rbha+psuoxNzVaQBoZpBxZGxgCNDABMphaW9SobqvcXpAGEorwBzOzgtT7igl-ekABRcpIMSqLzeDSzJrzHAPa7LJLbb6BchQD4wAD8gVuNl2CJoe2oB307Bg+CgMgqVWwpzEZ2wEySuV41CAA)